# Can I Use QuerySelector to Auto Select an item in <Li> and click on it

Tags: selector

Here is the code from the Website

```
<div class="select-size select-size-detail" id="sizeOptions" style="display: none;">
    <div></div>
    <ul class="select-box-size">
    <li currupc="00887231427970">7.5</li>                   
    <li currupc="00887231427987">8</li>
    <li currupc="00887231427994">8.5</li>
    <li currupc="00887231428007">9</li>
    <li currupc="00887231428014">9.5</li>
    <li currupc="00887231428021">10</li>
    <li currupc="00887231428038">10.5</li>
    <li currupc="00887231428045">11</li>
    <li currupc="00887231428069">12</li>
    <li currupc="00887231428083">13</li>
    </ul></div>
```

I tried both of these and it said

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '12' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:10

document.querySelectorAll("00887231428083").click();
document.querySelectorAll("13").click();
```

Anyone can help me, please 
I want to select a specific number and click on by plainjavascript or querySelector
thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
document.querySelector("li[currupc='00887231428083']")
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can select 12 instead of li[currupc='00887231428083'] Thanks

Comment: autually I want to make a script that can allow me to auto click on the size like 12 and the [currupc='00887231428083'] is different everytime Thanks

Comment: Then you have to add  "12" as some attribute Ex: value ="12". Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w577r64v/

Comment: If i don't add the attribute I can't use querySelector for "12"? is there anyway apart from querySelector that can allow me to auto select "12" thanks